# Минимальное количество товаров WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком файле WooCommerce или каким хуком можно изменить минимальное количество товаров(количество, ниже которого выводится надпись "Нет в наличие") в Woocommerce. 
Проблема в том, что если количество меньше 1, то выводиться эта надпись, а у меня количество товаров идёт по 0.7 и так далее.

Comment: woocommerce_notify_no_stock_amount

нашел вот это, только что с этим делать не знаю =\

Comment: в файле classes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php я нашел такой кусок кода

<br/>
// Out of stock attribute
   if ( ! $this->backorders_allowed() && $this->get_total_stock() <= 0 )
    $this->set_stock_status( 'outofstock' );
   elseif ( $this->backorders_allowed() || $this->get_total_stock() > 0 )
    $this->set_stock_status( 'instock' );

Получается, что стоит условие больше 0...

Comment: а я понял, там везде стоит intval, но я сомневаюсь что всё будет ок, если я просто впилю floatval